# Removing all showed marks Google API

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, google-maps

I work in Laravel project and I have module for displaying and removing all stores on a Google map if I choose only 1 store.

This is a duplicate question, however, why my function is not working setting the function `showallmarks` as null.

**Question:** How to remove all the marks displayed in the google maps once a button is clicked?

I have here the codes.

**Show all marks:**

```
showallmarks();

function showallmarks() {
  $.each(locations, function(index, value) {

    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(value.store_lat, value.store_long);
    var title = value.branch_name;
    var address = value.store_address;

    var contentString = "<h5>" + title + "</h5>" + address;

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: position,
      icon: google.maps.marker,
      map: map,
      zoom: 12
    });

    marker.addListener('click', function() {
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
  });
}
```

Once I click this button the `showallmarks` must not be shown on the Google map.

```
var markeronce;

$('button#addresses').click(function() {

  //removing all marks 
  showallmarks(null);

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "<span>Visit us on our store.</span>"
  });
  var address_href = $(this).val();
  var commaPos = address_href.indexOf(',');
  var coordinatesLat = parseFloat(address_href.substring(0, commaPos));
  var coordinatesLong = parseFloat(address_href.substring(commaPos + 1, address_href.length));

  var centerPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(coordinatesLat, coordinatesLong);


  if (!markeronce) {
    markeronce = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: centerPoint,
      map: map,
      zoom: 8
    });
  } else {
    markeronce.setPosition(centerPoint);
  }
  map.setCenter(centerPoint);
})
```

[image: Sample Image]

Comment: please try this demo https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Google-Maps-V3-Delete-Remove-Clear-all-markers.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Add Button like

```
  <input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="DeleteMarkers()" />
```

And try this function

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var markers = [];

    function DeleteMarkers() {
            //Loop through all the markers and remove
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                markers[i].setMap(null);
            }
            markers = [];
        };
    </script>
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: DeleteMarkers is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick